# Как можно передать значение из success (ajax)?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Есть ajax-запрос

```
               var user = "";
               $.ajax({
                    url: Url,
                    type:"GET",
                    success:function(data) {
                       user = data.user;                    
                    },
                    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                        console.log(xhr.responseText);
                    }
                });
                console.log (user);
```

`console.log` все равно выдает пустоту.

пробовала return делать из success, не помогло. 
Как можно передать значение из success ? подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас console.log вызывается раньше чем приходит ответ, соответственно либо перенесите console.log в success, либо используйте промисы почитать можно тут http://habrahabr.ru/post/209662/

UPD:
Самый простой вариант с jquery

```
var user = "";
$.ajax({
   url: Url,
   type:"GET",
}).done(function(data){
   console.log (data);
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
   console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
});
```

Comment: промисы некросбраузерны насколько я помню? или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Да, чет с с промисами я загнул, они только браузерами поддерживаются https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise В целом можно использовать http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/ он то вроде кроссбраузерный

Comment: использовала deferred-object. получилось так -  var Token = promise.done(function(data){return data.user;}); console.log(Token); / и console.log возвращает Object {readyState: 1} и кучу свойств. я конечно пробовала обращаться непосредственно в data.responseText , но все рано не отдает. В чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: Обновил ответ применительно jquery

Answer (score 1):

Вы делаете асинхронный запрос, т.е. `console.log (user);` выполняется еще до того, как будет получен ответ от сервера.

Таким образом у Вас два варианта.

1. Более корректный - учиться работать с асинхронными запросами.

   ```
   $.ajax({
       url: Url,
       type:"GET",
       success:function(data) {
           console.log (data);
           // тут какая-то логика обработки ответа и реакции на него  
           // или вызов какого-то колбека            
       },
       error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
           console.log(xhr.responseText);
       }
   });
   ```
2. Сделать запрос синхронным, добавив `async:false`, тогда все должно работать так, как Вы ожидаете. Но в целом, это не очень хорошая практика. А у меня, например, в хроме вообще запрещены синхронные ajax запросы. Тем не менее вот пример кода:

   ```
   var user = "";
   $.ajax({
       url: Url,
       type:"GET",
       async:false,
       success:function(data) {
           user = data.user;                  
       },
       error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
           console.log(xhr.responseText);
       }
   });
   console.log (user);
   ```

**PS** не проверял валидность кода, просто взял Ваш код за основу и добавил в него недостающие элементы.